# What is "parameters" in classification algorithm

Tags: algorithm, classification, weka

If I run a 5-fold cross validation on a particular data set on Weka, I will have a set of optimized parameter.

What is actually this parameter result that I am getting from a 5-fold cross validation?

How can I use this parameter to run another 10-fold cross validation on weka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which classification algorithm are you using?

Regardless, you can use weka's meta classifier, CVparameterSelection, to figure out the optimal values/combinations of input parameters for your classifier and then re-run with those values specified. For a pretty good explaination, check here: http://weka.wikispaces.com/Optimizing+parameters

Comment: I read the tutorial, but how can I re-run those values specified? can you show me some code?

Comment: @EquinoX: are you running in the Weka GUI or are you integrating in Java code?

Comment: I am integrating with java code, well... let me rephrase my previous question.. What I am trying to do is basically to write something like the CVparameterSelection manually, how can I do this?